# How to bind Request.QueryString[""] to Eval() in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, javascript

```
ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Name","../Master Pages/DisasterImages/") %>'+'<%#Eval("Request.QueryString["DisID"].ToString()/{0}") %>'
```

**DisID** is a folder name.

What I want is to display the images in the directory.
I have done it using a repeater control. The problem is now I want to get the folder name in the QueryString. How can I do this? Above is the code I have tried without achieving the desired outcome...

Any help would appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

use <%= instead of <%#. Example:

```
<%= Request.QueryString["DisID"] %>
```

I have noticed another issue with your code, you need to be careful when using quotes inside a string. You need to escape them. Therefore

```
"Request.QueryString["DisID"].ToString()/{0}"
```

should look like this

```
"Request.QueryString[\"DisID\"].ToString()/{0}"
```

Notice the backslash that serves for escaping characters.

Comment: hi Genady, the path i want to access is ../Master Pages/DisasterImages/XXX/{0}. XXX is the name i want to get from the QueryString.Still i haven't got it working.Following is what i have tried this time. ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Name","../Master Pages/DisasterImages/") %>'+'<%=Request.QueryString[\"DisID\"].ToString()/{0} %>'

Comment: You need not to call ToString when retrieving query string params since they are strings already. Are there any errors when the code is executed, why do you need the {0} string. What happens if you remove that part? Please keep in mind that the <%# expressions are only evaluated when one call DataBind on the respective control.

Comment: this did not work inside the aspx, instead of the variable the response is <%= Request.QueryString['DisID'] %>